# How do I reward the user daily?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, date, timer

I want to reward the user daily in my app, but when the app closes the timer always stops

I've tried doing this...

```
 Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 86400, repeats: true) { _ in
self.points += 100
}
```

Can you please tell me how to reward the user daily once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the timer stops; when you close Facebook, does the news feed keep scrolling? No, the answer is no. Especially as third party developers, we have to complete ALL our tasks prior to the data of the app closing. There are functions to keep working for up to ~5min but after that, any relevant data will close.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate

So, we need to consider how we can get around this. So, what we need to do is

1. Everytime the app opens, we check the date
2. If it is the FIRST time the user opens the app, we save the date LOCALLY (`UserDefaults`)
3. If not, we need to check if the date is the same day or a different day.
4. If it is the same day as the saved date, we do nothing
5. If it is a different day, we will provide the user our reward and then overwrite the date in our local save `UserDefaults`

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to call the function in the User Defaults (Store info locally). Here it is useful for calling functions only once like display the onboarding.

or on your DB you could set the timer there eg lambda functions on AWS

Comment: Could you perhaps give a little code, I'm not familiar with nsdate

Comment: This is how I would do it https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/task-timer-sample.html hope this helps

Comment: Is there one with NSDate? I don't want to use timestamps

Comment: You could create a function using javascript and it would update the database. thats just how I would do it. There probably is a solution doing it the way you want but I cant think of it atm sorry

Comment: I do not know javascript, is there a way I can use NSDate?

Comment: This is beyond complicated for a simple timer task that can be completed locally.